# Framework header not found in Xcode 4.2 but application runs fine

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, frameworks

I have a Mac app that uses a framework.

In build phases, I've added the framework to `Link Binary With Libraries` and created a `Copy Files` build phase to copy the framework. Furthermore, I'ved added the framework search paths to `Framework Search Paths`, `Header Search Paths`, and `User Header Search Paths`. The path is as follows:

`../UMEKit/DerivedData/UMEKit/Build/Products/Release`

I can build and run the application however next to the header import statement `#import "UMEKit/UMEKit.h"`, there is a red maker indicating that the header is not found.

I've also tried restarting Xcode and my computer a billion times and haven't been able to resolve the problem.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use quotes when importing something from a framework. Use <> instead. For example

```
#import <UMEKit/UMEKit.h>
```

This will work.